# Maps functionality in a list

Tags: list, google-maps

I want a field in my list to be able to do the following:

1. Display an interactive map,
2. When I click  it a pin is dropped on that location, 
   I enter a Title and a description for that location,
3. The long/lat are saved automatically,

It needs to be able so save many locations/pins.

Is this possible? If so could I get some feeback or links on how to do this?

I'm using SharePoint Online.

Comment: How many blogs have you found? And what is not working for you? We are here to help, not do your job.

Comment: Ive looked at a bunch of links covering the "geolocation field". All of them are a bit basic in its functionality though. I didnt ask for a solution, i just want to know if this is possible and maybe have a link or to covering something that looks like the scenario i described.

Comment: Also im not a sharepoint developer and not familiar with the terms for SP. So maybe some help on what Im supposed to look for.

Comment: No worries, we see you are new here. The whole concept of StackOverflow is that you post what you tried sofar. So you list blogs and code that you tried. Any question "Is xyz" possible can be answered with Yes

Answer (score 2):

I made a step-by-step guide on how to get the bing maps feature into a list.

Also it is a little improved, so you can just type in the e.g. city and it will automatically add the longitude and latitude.

Maybe this helps you a little bit.

**Update:**
Tested this only for SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

https://afrait.com/blog/geolocation-field-bing-maps-integration-de/

That's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Hi Patrick, the blog link in in German language. Is there link in English?

Comment: I am sorry, no! But is this what you are looking for? Maybe I can help you anyway

Comment: Thank you Patrick! I think they way i will solve my case is to create a custom view for creating a new list entry, this way i dont have to create it in "Excel mode".

Comment: Bing maps works with SharePoint online, but for me PowerShell didn't work and it was necessary run to CSOM code.